# New code went AWOL, left old revision. Where did it go?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I just opened up a project I last worked on two weeks ago and discovered that my working version is several revisions behind (using Mercurial via Bitbucket). The latest **compiled assemblies** on my dev machine are 100% up-to-date, but my local and remote code repositories are missing all the new code, which I compiled on my dev machine into the latest assemblies.

Disassembling the latest compile (a month old) using Red Gate's [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), I can see all my newest code, but none of that is now anywhere to be found on my dev machine, or in any of my repositories. It's like all my code went *back to the future*. Is it possible I inadvertently reverted and overrode some code from my remote repository and there is no trail of it?

I must not have committed my latest changes, but surely these should still be in my working copy? I am unaware of any system roll-backs. I run Visual Studio 2010 on my Windows 7 dev box and I am sure this is not Mercurial's fault, but is there some functionality I am not aware of? How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not-committing is *always* a bad idea, committing is how you say "this is something" not "this is finished".

What is the output of `hg summary`?  Is it possible you've `hg update`d to a past revision -- if so all the new stuff is still in the repo, just not the working directory.  Mercurial never throws away committed changes, and only gets rid of uncommitted changes if you use an option like `--clean` on update.  If you did `hg revert` you'll have `.orig` backup files unless you did a `--no-backup`.

In brief, Mercurial won't throw away changes unless you work very hard at it, so either they're still there or it was something external.

Comment: YYEEEEEEESSS!!!! My newer versions are in the .orig files. How do I tell Mercurial to replace my current (out-dated) version with the (newer) .orig files? I shall have Jon Skeet bring you a fresh pot of coffee.

Comment: Nevermind, sorted it using `for /f %i in ('dir /s /b *.orig') do @copy %i %~dpni` to replace the working copy with the .orig files.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Be careful with revert if you're not habitually committing.  Or better yet commit compulsively. :)